# Hand-picked items in the training set, good idea?

Tags: representative

The training, validation and test sets for the classification problem I'm working on were randomly sampled from real data. Because of this, I am fairly confident that there are representative.

I want to allow humans to report misclassifications. These reports would get used as additional training data (but not validation or test data). With enough of these reports, the training data would lose its representative property, as it would contain a higher fraction of tricky cases then would be found in the real application of the classifier.

Is this a problem? How important is it for the training set to be representative?